# Basic questions about convergence of spectral sequences.

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I have a fairly rudimentary understanding of spectral sequences. I have a couple questions though.

In Algebra, Lang states what seems to me, to be two slightly different notion of convergence of a spectral sequence.

He says that if $E_r^{p,q}=E_{r+1}^{p,q}=...$ then the spectral sequence converges to $E_{\infty}^{p,q}$.

But later he says that in the case of a double complex, or more generally a filtered complexe we usually say that the associated spectral sequence converges to the homology of the complex, to mean that the spectral sequence converges to the graded groups associated with the filtration induced on the homology of the complex. In other words we say that $E_r^{p,q}$ converges to $H^{p+q}(C_\bullet)$ to mean that $E_r^{p,q}$ converges to $Gr^p(H^{p+q}(C_\bullet)$.

This has caused me no trouble up until now, as I have only encountered spectral sequences coming from double complexes.

However I'm a bit puzzeled when I encounter that kind of sentence (this is the first example that comes to my mind, maybe that's not the most elementary).

There is a spectral sequence whose 2nd sheet is $H^{p-q, -q}(F, \mathbb{Z})$ that converges to $K_{-p-q}(F)$ for a field $F$.

Does that mean that $E_{\infty}^{p,q}=K_{-p-q}(F)$ (which I don't believe), or that there exist a filtration on $K_{-p-q}(F)$ whose associated graded groups are $E_{\infty}^{p,q}$. And if it's the latter, how do I find the filtration?

I'm a bit lost because in the proof, it is done by exhibiting a so-called "exact couple", and I don't see where the filtration comes into play, and how I should interpret the general statement of the theorem.

Comment: I believe you have a typo: you want "whose 2nd sheet is $H^{-p,-q}$" - yes?

Comment: Mmmh, no I believe this is the correct term. Sometimes it is written differently though as $H^{p,-q/2}(F)$ with of course the convention that it is 0, if the index is not an integer.

Comment: Well - then I am confused! Unless its $K_{p-2q} $? Because I would have said that the  $E^{n-\cdot,\cdot}_r$ is to calculate $Gr^\cdot ( H^{n})$. e.g., group cohomology and the $E_2$ term:$$ 0\rightarrow H^1(G/K, H^0(K,M) )\rightarrow H^1(G,M)\rightarrow H^0(G/K, H^1(K,M)\rightarrow H^2(G/K,M^K) \cdots$$ aka, the inflation restriction sequence i.e., the $p+q = n$.    But maybe my $K$-ignorance is messing me up?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your objection. In my case the $H^{p-q,-q}(F,\mathbb Z)$ is the motivic cohomology.
But in any case I don't really understand where this spectral sequence comes from yet, but first I'd like to know how to correctly interpret the statement.

Comment: My objection - although I am going to bow out now, for fear that I am being a moron - is that  the indices in $H^{p-q,-q}$ add up to $p-2q$, whereas in $E^{p,q}_\infty$ or $K_{-p-q}$ the indices add up to $p+q$, or $-(p+q)$. I am objecting to $p+q \ne p -2q$ (up to sign). Sorry if I am being a moron!

Comment: @peterag If that is motivic cohomology, the second exponent does not corresponds to a grading of a double complex. It is rather $H^{pq}=H^p(.,\mathbb{Z}(q))$ where $\mathbb{Z}(q)$ is of weight $-2q$. Hence the "total degree" is $(p-q)+2q=-(-p-q)$ which is fine.

Comment: Thanks @Roland... I was looking it up too and had already established, as I had conjectured above, that I am a moron.... Oh  well.